# How to write a jQuery variable to a text file with AJAX/PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery variable. It's a text string. I want to create a .txt file on the server, then write that string to the text file.

How do I trigger this without reloading the page? I know PHP will have to get involved somewhere...

My attempts to do this with `$.ajax();` haven't worked.

Comment: What do those attempts look like? You'll probably get better answers by providing some code you've already tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pass this variable to a php script:

```
var data = 'foo bar';
$.post('/foo.php', { data: data }, function(result) {
    // success
    alert('the data was successfully sent to the server');
});
```

or if you prefer using [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
var data = 'foo bar';
$.ajax({
    url: '/foo.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { data: data },
    success: function(result) {
        alert('the data was successfully sent to the server');
    }
});
```

and then inside your `foo.php` script read the data from `$_POST["data"]` and [save the contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) to some file on the server.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for clarifying the part about $_POST["data"]. That's where I was getting caught before.